# canvas element or dynamic form generator

Tags: java, canvas

I need a form made of a variable number of rows and cols (choosable by user) in which I can insert values and process them.

My question is: is it possible using the canvas or should I do it using just java script? Keep in mind that I need the table format (rows and cols aligned, no matter the length of the data inserted) for the data to be inserted as it is important for the information to be structured in a way easy to read by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Canvas for a table is probably not a very good idea. You would have to do all rendering, positioning, scrolling, selecting, editing, etc yourself. That's a lot of work. Use a table element and manipulate it with javascript and/or jQuery. Or consider using the DataTables plugin or similar plugins.